# Showing a language is a subset of another language?

Tags: formal-languages

I'm actually trying to give an example of a language being context-free and its superset that isn't context-free. I came up with this, but I'm not sure if this particular language is a superset of the other.

Let A be a context-free language. A = {a^n b^n | n >= 0}.

Let B be a non context-free language. B = {a^n b^n c^n | n >= 0}.

What I'm not sure of is if A is a subset of B. I saw something regarding proving if a regular language is a subset of another regular language, but I don't know if it applies to this situation.

Can someone provide some clarity on this, please?

Comment: It's just the usual definition of subset from mathematics. To show that $X$ is a subset of $Y$, you just show that everything that is in $X$ is in $Y$; to show that it's not a subset, show that there's something in $X$ that isn't in $Y$. Since you have closed-form definitions of the two languages, it's completely irrelevant that one of them is context-free and the other isn't: they're just sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A language $B$ is a superset of another language $A$ if it contains all the strings of $A$ and some more. In your example, $A$ contains $ab$, but $B$ only contains string with $c$'s in them, so $ab\not\in B$, so $B$ is not a superset of $A$, i.e. $A \not\subseteq B$.

What you are looking for is a language $B$ which is not context-free but which does contain all of $A$. For example, you could let $C$ be some very difficult language, for example, the language of TMs that halt on the empty tape, or the language of prime numbers, and let $B=A\cup C$. Then whatever the complexity it $B$, you can be sure that it's not context-free. This trick won't always work. For example, if $A=\Sigma^{*}$, then no superset of $A$ *exists*, and certainly not one that isn't context-free.

What you read about one language a subset of another language is probably succinctly captured in [the Wikipediag page on context-free languages (link)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language) and [that of regular languages (link)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language#Closure_properties) under the section of *closure properties*. A closure property is a theorem states that, for example, if $L_1$ and $L_2$ are both context-free, then $L_1 \cup L_2$ is also a context-free language. In this case you can say *context-free languages are closed under union*.

Comment: Something came to mind: is it possible for the union of the language of prime numbers with a another language (CFL or not) to be a CFL? Are there languages that, when combined with other languages through union that will never give a resulting language that is a CFL?

Comment: @LaserTaser Sure, you can do that. For example, the language $C$ of composite numbers is not context-free, and the language of prime numbers $P$ is not context-free, but since _every_ number is either composite or prime, the language $C\cup P=\Sigma^{*}$ is the set of all strings, which is regular, and therefore context-free. Another example: if $E$ is the language of even numbers, then $E$ is regular (and therefore context-free) and $E\cap P=\{2\}$ because $2$ is the only even prime. So yes: in general, taking the union or intersection of languages can make them easier.

Comment: The above reasoning is dangerous, in my opinion. First, it states "you can be sure that it's not context-free", which is immediately retracted by "This trick won't always work". I regard it as dangerous since it _seems_ to imply that, when $C$ is difficult, $A \cup C$ will be difficult, which is false, in general. Indeed, if $C$ is the set of primes, it might even be that $C\subseteq A$ depending on how primes are encoded into strings. Still, the intuition is the correct one.